# Recursive CSS Layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive layout based on the Golden Ratio (1:1.618) and I want it to be infinitely recursive.

I know, it will never be used after so many layers deep, but I started obsessing over the fact that I can't figure out how to make it infinitely recursive!

Here it is:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**
*
* GOLDEN RATIO LAYOUT
*
**/

/**
* Default layout is left to right, top to bottom
* To use the Golden Ratio Layout, create a container.
* Within that container, have only two childen.
* The first child should have the class .large-side,
* and the second child should have the class .small-side .
* I suggest nesting layouts on the small side, where the
* element would have .small-side and .golden-ratio-layout .
**/

.golden-ratio-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .large-side {
    flex: 1.618 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .small-side {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .panel-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Standard flow */
.golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* Reverse flow */
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    /* Standard flow */
    .golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    /* Reverse flow */
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="top golden-ratio-layout">
    <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
        <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
        <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
            <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
            <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
                <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
                <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
                    <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-side panel-wrapper" >
                    <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks pretty good, right?

Odds are, this will be all that is ever needed, as we probably don't want to exceed five panels, but look at what happens when we add a sixth panel:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**
*
* GOLDEN RATIO LAYOUT
*
**/

/**
* Default layout is left to right, top to bottom
* To use the Golden Ratio Layout, create a container.
* Within that container, have only two childen.
* The first child should have the class .large-side,
* and the second child should have the class .small-side .
* I suggest nesting layouts on the small side, where the
* element would have .small-side and .golden-ratio-layout .
**/

.golden-ratio-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .large-side {
    flex: 1.618 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .small-side {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .panel-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Standard flow */
.golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

/* Reverse flow */
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    /* Standard flow */
    .golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    /* Reverse flow */
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reverse > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="top golden-ratio-layout">
    <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
        <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
        <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
            <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
            <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
                <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
                <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
                    <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout" >
                    <div class="large-side panel-wrapper" >
                        <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >5</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-side panel-wrapper" >
                        <div class="golden-ratio-panel" >6</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It didn't work!

Well, lets look at the last `.golden-ratio-layout`.

We could target this element with:

```
.golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: {{ whatever }};
}
```

If we add that rule, it will be fixed, but then we would be assuring that we need to add rules for every level of depth that we want to support.

So, how could we support infinite depth levels of these nested rules?
Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not so sure about the infinite part, but you should consider removing the padding from `.panel-wrapper` and making `.golden-ratio-layout` have `box-sizing: border-box`. That will solve _most_ of the layout overlapping issues.

Comment: @chazsolo You were seeing panel overlapping issues?! What browser? I always add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` anyway. I'll add that to my snippets.

Comment: @chazsolo Also, the padding wasn't there for arrangement. It's there for visually separating the panels and making room for the shadows.

Comment: Ah sorry, not overlapping (other than #6 overlapping #2) - I meant the gaps. When rendering out panels like this it's usually a good idea to let the content drive the separation between panels (so the panels themselves are actually right next to each other)

Comment: @chazsolo Hmm... ok. I can agree with that. It was mostly for representation here.

Comment: Other than using a preprocessor I think writing it out by hand would be the only way (that I know of). [Here's a fiddle to show what I was talking about as far as the layout is concerned.](https://jsfiddle.net/chazsolo/0zeh9f8m/6/)

Comment: @chazsolo I'm going to update the snippets to remove the padding and shadows. I think it will be better for readers who want to use this. You may be right. I think a preprocessor may be the only way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues.

The first is with your HTML.  In your working example you repeat the pattern of *golden-ratio-layout* -> *panel-wrapper* -> *golden-ratio-panel*.  But in your broken example you omit golden-ratio-layout in the last level.  Adding that will fix the glitchy behavior, but it won't fix everything.

The second problem is past the fourth level your just going to keep adding boxes on top of boxes - the spiral you're going for won't repeat.  You can see what happens if you add colors to the background.  The rule that specifies the fourth level of golden-ratio-layout is just repeated, where your intention is to repeat all four rules starting from the first.

To fix this issue I had to resort to adding a *reset* class add applying it to every fourth div starting from the first.  I rewrote the CSS rules that change the `flex-direction` so the top-most class in the rule was *reset*. If I could have figured out how to use a pseudo-selector instead I would've done it.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.golden-ratio-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .large-side {
    flex: 1.618 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout > .small-side {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .panel-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px #024;
}
.golden-ratio-layout .golden-ratio-panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Relevant changes past this point */
/* Standard flow */
.golden-ratio-layout.reset {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #800;
    color: white;
   
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #601;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background: #402;
}
.golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    background: #203;
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    /* Standard flow */
    .golden-ratio-layout.reset  {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .golden-ratio-layout.reset  > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout > .golden-ratio-layout {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="top golden-ratio-layout reset">
  <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
    <div class="golden-ratio-panel">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout">
    <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
      <div class="golden-ratio-panel">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout">
      <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
        <div class="golden-ratio-panel">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout">
        <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
          <div class="golden-ratio-panel">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout reset">
          <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
            <div class="golden-ratio-panel">5</div>
          </div>
          <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout">
            <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
              <div class="golden-ratio-panel">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-side golden-ratio-layout reset">
              <div class="large-side panel-wrapper">
                <div class="golden-ratio-panel">7</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```